# Conditional formatting attribute table in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

Can you make the same conditional formatting on an attribute table added to the printcomposer as you can do within the attribute table? (with QGIS 2.16.3)

Comment: Facing the same need, I did not found any feature request about it.
I just create a new one: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17406

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so, might be a good idea to post this as a [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis).

Saying that, there are some options which allows you to enable shading for matching cells in:

```
Item Properties > Appearence > Advanced customisation...
```

[image: Table shading]

Since there are already existing options to apply shading to certain order of cells, it should be possible to add a custom expression somewhere.

Comment: I know the advanced customisation that way.  But I want to highlight only features matching a certain value.

Comment: @PieterB - In the `Feature filtering` section (above the `Appearence` section`), there is the **Filter with** option. You could use this to filter the entire attribute table for only the features you want which matches a certain value. Note that the attributes of the features which do not match your value will not be shown.